# Massive loss of rep

Tags: discussion

I'm used to the occasional 100 points or so disappearing from my rep due to deleted users. I grumble to myself about it and then get on with life because the site is about learning Japanese, not about gaining rep.

However, I just noticed today that I've lost 1,700 points due to one deleted user. This seems a bit extreme. It's going to take me quite a bit more grumbling to get over that loss.

Was this user deleted for voting irregularities or are we being punished just because they decided to leave the site even though their previous votes were all reasonable? If it's the former it would be nice to have some way of being informed of this. If it's the latter then the system seems a little broken to me.

Comment: It was the latter. But what is the solution? If votes remained in effect people would abuse that system for reputation. Even with rules like having had to be a member for so long and the Q or A having to be a certain number of years old for the vote to remain, the fact remains that the same person could have more than one vote.

Comment: @By137 Sorry, I'm being a bit dumb. I don't see how this could be used to cheat the system.

Comment: Re: "It's going to take me quite a bit more grumbling to get over that loss", look on the bright side: your posts, your contributions, were appreciated by one of the brightest minds this site has seen and we have had the privilege of knowing and brushing shoulders with.

Comment: Uh oh, I might be the one being a bit dumb. I was just referring to the ability to delete an account make a new one and vote again. Is that not possible?

Comment: For the record, I [lost 13792 reps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBVAI.png) in one day. Of course I'm more sad that she's gone than that I lost my reps...

Comment: Sorry, but you are in for another shock, probably a bigger one this time, because I just noticed a pretty huge drop in your rep.

Comment: @EddieKal  I feel like sisyphus rolling his boulder. 30k rep is the top of the hill. Any idea who's gone this time?

Comment: Just figured it out. Looks like l'electeur has gone. Another big loss.

Comment: Yeah, very helpful contributor; quite a character also, I think.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, snailplane, one of our moderators, has left the site.

She was an ardent voter. Usually only part of the votes are undone when an account is deleted (unless the account is deleted for voting irregularities, which was certainly not the case), so the unvotes we are seeing are just the tip of the iceberg of the enormous work she has done for this community.

I think I speak for everyone if I say that we are all very sorry to see her go — personally, I still can't quite believe this really happened... (If you're reading this, I do hope we will see you again some time, and if not I truly wish you all the best!)

Comment: That is a sad loss. I'd noticed that she hadn't been around for quite some time.

Comment: Any background on what happened?  This is a very drastic change, and it is difficult to accept.  If someone as consistently constructive as snailplane can be forcibly removed, I find myself questioning the foundation of the JSE administrative base...  Any additional information to try to make sense of this would be most appreciated.

Comment: @Eirikr I believe that she left voluntarily, so I guess "life" is what happened...

Comment: @Earthliŋ, if it's just that she feels "done" and doesn't want to participate anymore, it seems very out of line for site admins to completely remove her account, which essentially erases her contributions.  Doing so is a negative for the site and the community.  Why not just leave her posts, votes, etc. in place?

Comment: If there are site rule transgressions the account would simply be suspended. If the user does not visit the site for a longer period, nothing happens either. Stack Exchange staff only remove an account if the user asks for it (note that ordinary site moderators cannot do this). But even upon removal all posts and the better part of the votes are kept. Just that in the case at hand, the removed part of the votes was still quite impressive...

Comment: @Earthliŋ, thank you, it's helpful to understand the internal rules for how this works.  I appreciate your candor.